# Does vhost order make a difference?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, redhat, virtualhost

On our Centos webserver, Apache has a httpd.conf file which lists several vhost.conf files. We have five of these files for different sets of domains. One vhost.conf file can have hundreds of domains, and hundreds of 301 redirects. I understand that the first vhost is used for fallback. This server has a heavy load. About 10-20 domains serve maybe 80% or more of all traffic.

I wonder if the order of the vhost files and - inside one vhost file - the order of the different domains can make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vhost definitions are inserted into a hash table during initialization, so the overhead of looking them up is minimal, and order is likely irrelevant (except for the first one, as you mentioned). You can [read about the details in the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html). They also have a [page on performance tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html#runtime), where no mention is made of ordering.

Answer (score 2):

I have inherited systems which had hundreds of virtual domains configured, in no particular order, which I then sorted alphabetically for ease of access. The sorting had absolutely no effect on the speed of the server. However, the plural of anecdote is not data, so don't take my word for it.